# Using one table/model in two different EDMX maps

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

So I had a functioning Ado.Net project with a mysql database using EntityFramework.  I have several tables, all of which had latitude and longitude fields.  I recently added a coordinate_addresses table, and modified all my existing tables with lat/long fields by replacing said fields with a coordinate_address_id field.  Now, pretty much all of my queries fail with the following error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

The relationship 'myModel.device_locations_ibfk_2' was not loaded because the type 'myModel.coordinate_addresses' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'device_locations' does not exist on the type 'myNamespace.Database_Maps.coordinate_addresses'.
```

There are actually several of these errors where the relationship changes but the required property remains the same.  I have entirely recreated my EDMX maps to no success.

If any more information is required I will do my best to provide it!

EDIT: So I have two EDMX files.  When I run custom tool on one, it removes coordinate_addresses from the other.  In effect every time I fixed one EDMX I broke the other. Can I not use the same model in two different db connectors?  Please assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your edmx files are in the same namespace, try changing them. chances are custom finds it conflicting to create two objects with the same name in the same namespace.

Comment: Both my EDMX files are in my "Database Maps" folder, which then becomes the namespace.  You are saying I need a folder for every map??

Comment: I am suggesting you to try that..I dont immediately see any other reason why a same table cannot exist in both the edmx files.

Comment: this was indeed the problem.  there must be a better solution

Comment: If you are using a custom code generation tool to generate classes from edmx.. you can modify the .tt file to mention the namespace... if this appeals.